# performSelectorInBackground with multiple params

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I call a method with multiple params like below with performSelectorInBackground?

Sample method:

```
-(void) reloadPage:(NSInteger)pageIndex firstCase:(BOOL)firstCase;
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem is that `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` takes only one object argument. One way to get around this limitation is to pass a dictionary (or array) of arguments to a "wrapper" method that deconstructs the arguments and calls your actual method:

```
- (void)callingMethod {
    NSDictionary * args = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSNumber numberWithInteger:pageIndex], @"pageIndex",
                            [NSNumber numberWithBool:firstCase], @"firstCase",
                            nil];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(reloadPageWrapper:)
                           withObject:args];
}

- (void)reloadPageWrapper:(NSDictionary *)args {
    [self reloadPage:[[args objectForKey:@"pageIndex"] integerValue]
           firstCase:[[args objectForKey:@"firstCase"] boolValue]];
}

- (void)reloadPage:(NSInteger)pageIndex firstCase:(BOOL)firstCase {
    // Your code here...
}
```

This way you're only passing a "single" argument to the backgrounding call, but that method can construct the multiple arguments you need for the real call (which will take place on the same backgrounded thread).

Comment: By using the NSInvocation class and variable arguments list one could write a very elegant generic wrapper class.. Maybe the next time i need to write just another wrapper i'll give it a try!

Comment: @hariseldon78 +1 you inspired me to write such a thing, check out my answer.

Comment: These days you should really use dispatch_async(...) to do something like this, rather than -performSelectorInBackground:...

Answer (score 6):

Well, I have used this:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(reloadPage:)
                       withObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:pageIndex,firstCase,nil] ];
```

for this:

```
- (void) reloadPage: (NSArray *) args {
    NSString *pageIndex = [args objectAtIndex:0];    
    NSString *firstCase = [args objectAtIndex:1];    
}
```

Comment: This will leak an `NSArray`. You should use `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]` instead of `[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...]`.

Comment: Thanks respectTheCode, I'm lazy so I always use autorelease. Thanks anyways.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work unless the selector I am performing is expecting an array. Otherwise it things the first parameter in the selector should be the array.

Comment: You didn't correct the alloc problem pointed out by @respectTheCode and also the expected argument by function should be an NSArray if your performSelector example were to work as pointed out by Will.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The reported problems have been resolved.

Answer (score 6):

I've just found this question and wasn't happy with any of the answers. In my opinion neither make good use of the tools available, and passing around arbitrary information in arrays and dictionaries generally worries me.

So, I went and wrote a small `NSObject` category that will invoke an arbitrary selector with a variable number of arguments:

**Category Header**

```
@interface NSObject (NxAdditions)

-(void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)selector withObjects:(id)object, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;

@end
```

**Category Implementation**

```
@implementation NSObject (NxAdditions)

-(void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)selector withObjects:(id)object, ...
{
    NSMethodSignature *signature = [self methodSignatureForSelector:selector];

    // Setup the invocation
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
    invocation.target = self;
    invocation.selector = selector;

    // Associate the arguments
    va_list objects;
    va_start(objects, object);
    unsigned int objectCounter = 2;
    for (id obj = object; obj != nil; obj = va_arg(objects, id))
    {
        [invocation setArgument:&obj atIndex:objectCounter++];
    }
    va_end(objects);

    // Make sure to invoke on a background queue
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithInvocation:invocation];
    NSOperationQueue *backgroundQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [backgroundQueue addOperation:operation];
}

@end
```

**Usage**

```
-(void)backgroundMethodWithAString:(NSString *)someString array:(NSArray *)array andDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSLog(@"String: %@", someString);
    NSLog(@"Array: %@", array);
    NSLog(@"Dict: %@", dict);
}

-(void)someOtherMethod
{
    NSString *str = @"Hello world";
    NSArray *arr = @[@(1337), @(42)];
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"site" : @"Stack Overflow",
                           @"url" : [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"]};

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundMethodWithAString:array:andDictionary:)
                          withObjects:str, arr, dict, nil];
}
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

with performSelectorInBackground you can only pass one argument, so make a custom object for this method to hold your data, itll be more concise than an ambiguous dictionary or array.  The benefit of this is you can pass the same object around when done containing several return properties.

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ObjectToPassToMethod : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *inputValue1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *inputArray;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger returnValue1;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger returnValue2;

@end
```

and pass that object to your method:

```c
ObjectToPassToMethod *obj = [[ObjectToPassToMethod alloc] init];
obj.inputArray = @[];
obj.inputValue1 = @"value";
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundMethod:) withObject:obj];


-(void)backgroundMethod:(ObjectToPassToMethod*)obj
{
    obj.returnValue1 = 3;
    obj.returnValue2 = 90;
}
```

make sure to clean up the object when done to prevent memory leaks