# Struggling to pass multiple parameters to performSelectorInBackground method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parameters, selector

I found this [piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299629/performselectorinbackground-with-multiple-params) from an earlier Stack Overflow question which describes how to pass multiple parameters to a performSelectorInBackground method.

However I'm struggling to apply the code to my problem, here is MY code:

```
- (void)callingMethod {
    NSDictionary * args = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           cell, @"cell",
                           storyIndex, @"storyIndex",
                           nil];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setCellImageWrapper:)
                           withObject:args];
}

- (void)setCellImageWrapper:(NSDictionary *)args {
    [self setCellImage:[[args objectForKey:@"cell"]]
             withIndex:[[args objectForKey:@"storyIndex"] intValue]];
}

- (void) setCellImage: (EventTableCell *)cell withIndex:(int)storyIndex {

    //My Code

}
```

As you can see I'm trying to pass an object of type EventTableCell to the setCellImage method from the setCellImageWrapper method.  I'm getting the error "Expected Identifier" when I try to call the setCellImage -withIndex method.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you remove the extra brackets around the

```
[args objectForKey:@"cell"]
```

it should compile fine

Comment: Yeh I missed that as well, I also hadn't declared the method in the header file either, seems I had just been looking at the code too long and I missed it.. Thanks @drewag