# Alternative to GCD dispatch queues

Tags: macos, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch, osx-leopard

For several reasons, I would like to make my application backwards compatible to OS X 10.5.

Until now, I am using lots of GCD dispatch queues added in 10.6 like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self setStatusText:@"Connection established, waiting for response ..."
               withType:STATUS_MSG_INFO];

});
```

What would be the easiest alternative so that I don't have to re-write all the code?

Suggestions welcome! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following NSObject method:

```
- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that one, you can't execute larger blocks though. But I think that's a drawback I'm gonna have to handle ... What about if I need something on a different thread? Is there something such as thread-pooling in OS X prior to 10.6?

Comment: With performSelectorXXX, you would be using method calls instead of blocks. I'm not aware of stock thread pooling, but there are probably open-source solutions that provide them.

Comment: I was just wondering how you would call the method mentioned above (with more than one argument), found an easy solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299629/performselectorinbackground-with-multiple-params

Comment: What about `NSOperationQueue`?