# Passing NSData to web service along with NSDictionary Parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have all the AFNetworking Services written in Separate web service classe. upto now i have been doing it fine passing NSDictionary parameters. but now i got a problem when i need to pass NSData file to web service.

Here how im performing web service

```
 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profileImg.image, 0.5); // I need to pass this imageData

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];

    NSString *stringFromDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    //Encrypting Password
    NSString *passwordString = _password.text;
    NSString *passwordMD5 = [passwordString MD5String];

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"username": _username.text,
                             @"password": passwordMD5,
                             @"email": _email.text,
                             @"date":stringFromDate};

    WebService *serviceObj = [[WebService alloc] init];
    serviceObj.delegate = self;
    [serviceObj performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doRegister:) withObject:params];
```

Here how i have written web service

```
NSMutableDictionary * parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:params];

NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/register.php"];

AFHTTPSessionManager * manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:@"" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image" fileName:@"profile.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];

} progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

    [delegate didReceiveRegisterResponse:responseObject];

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

}];
```

but i dont know how to assign that imagedata now.

Answer (score 0):

I Have done it passing NSData and NSDictionary inside array. like below

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(reloadPage:)
                       withObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:pageIndex,firstCase,nil] ];


- (void) reloadPage: (NSArray *) args {
    NSString *pageIndex = [args objectAtIndex:0];    
    NSString *firstCase = [args objectAtIndex:1];    
}
```

Got the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299629/performselectorinbackground-with-multiple-params)